# SPA from url not on root (and including a filename.aspx) routing and refresh

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a SPA, I want to use routing for ng-view.

I have the code included in a page at `domain.com/folder/dashboard.aspx`
This is just a piece of that existing page, I can't move it elsewhere.

When I use route /list it alters my url to `domain.com/folder/list/` which works, but breaks the ability to refresh the page **(and gives a 404 since dashboard.aspx is not a default page, nor can it be)**

How can I keep the url as `domain.com/folder/dashboard.aspx/list`?

I did try to setup my routes as dashboard.aspx/list and other various similar adjustments, but didn't have any luck.

Comment: this isn't specifically solved by angularjs, this is something related to your server;  you need to set up a redirect on your server to load your page on non-existent URLs;  how you do this depends on what server you are using.

Comment: I have no way of touching the server, It as an existing business application and I'm only allowed to add code to that single page.

Comment: You have no choice in the matter.  This is behavior that cannot be handled by the browser.  You *might* be able to use the history API to change the path, but a reload would reset your app entirely in that instance.

Comment: I figured it out, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.

You can't use HTML5 mode, you have to be using Hashbang.

I set my routes as normal, `/list` and `/list/item`
For my links, I just used full urls, with the `Dashboard.aspx#!/list/item` and `/list`

I also removed the base tag from the html page

Answer (score 2):

Just like what @Claies said, it should be handled in your server config, just gonna drop my route config here in case you haven't tried this yet

```
var routeWithoutResolving = function (template: string, title?: string, style?: string) {
    var name;
    var slashIdx = template.indexOf('/');

    if (slashIdx !== -1) {
        name = template.substring(0, slashIdx);
        template = template.substring(slashIdx + 1);
    } else {
        name = template;
    }

    var templateUrl = '/folder/' + template + '.aspx/';

    return {
        templateUrl: templateUrl,
        title: title,
        style: style,
        area: _.capitalize(name),
        page: template,
        reloadOnSearch: false
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
.when('/domain.com/folder/dashboard.aspx/list', routeWithoutResolving ('folder/dashboard.aspx'))
```

Comment: I have no way of touching the server config. This is an existing page on an already running server for a different application. I have the ability to add code directly to that page only.